# Checking if a image exists

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to check if the file exists before I use it on the page.  From what I understand something like this should work but nothing appears so I am assuming I have not coded it correctly.

```
<?php 
    $url = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    $page_id = get_queried_object_id();    

        if(file_exists( $url . '/images/footerImage' . $page_id . '.png')) { ?>
            <img class="footerImage" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/footerImage<?php echo $page_id; ?>.png" />
        <?php } ?>
```

I want it to check to see if the file exists and if it does create the image tag, if not do nothing.  Why is this not showing any images?  I know I have the images because it was working before I had the if statement but creating a broken image  on a page that I did not have an image for.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$url`?

Comment: This would be a lot more efficient (and probably less error prone) if you used filesystem references for your images rather than urls

Comment: file_exists looks for files on the server not urls.  There are some examples for finding if a url exists on the file_exists doc page http://au2.php.net/file_exists

Comment: you can use fopen if you like..

Comment: When you assemble the full name of the file for the HTML output, put it in a variable rather than building it multiple times. It's also wasteful to jump in and out of PHP like that -- just echo out the img tag from PHP. file_exists() wants a filesystem path (relative or, better yet, absolute), not a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_bloginfo('template_directory')` function returns the Absolute URL. But you need to supply the Relative path in order to check the file existence  `file_exists()`

```
if(file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/images/footerImage' . $page_id . '.png')) { ?>
        <img class="footerImage" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/footerImage<?php echo $page_id; ?>.png" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` return like `http://domain.com/upload/....png`, But `file_exists()` function require `/var/www/html/yourproject/upload/images...png`

Comment: I see you updated it right after I asked for some code.  Thanks I understand now once I saw it I always get confused with these situations.  Thank you!

Comment: @Fogolicious, Yeah, no issues.

Comment: Yeah, no issues. It works great!  Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.